# “Loi à tiroirs”: what does it mean?

Tags: sens, expressions

In this [text](http://www.aleteia.org/fr/societe/actualites/outre-mer-sus-aux-jours-feries-catholiques-5797412614438912), how can I translate the expression “avec cette loi à tiroirs”? Do they mean that the law decree is on-hold, suspended, or something similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here, the "tiroirs" is not any legalistic technical term. It's literally comparing the law to a complicated chest of drawers with bad surprises hidden in its nook and crannies. Something like [this piece of furniture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKikHxKeodA), to be precise. I wouldn't be entirely sure what to compare it to in the translation, though.

Comment: Can't be more precise.